# nginx "starts with" regex

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm trying to block/allow access to a particular vhost based on string matching of the HTTP user agent name.

The version number of the application in the HTTP user agent changes, e.g.

```
My%20App/1.55.01 CFNetwork/711.5.6 Darwin/14.0.0
My%20App/1.49.03 CFNetwork/711.5.6 Darwin/14.0.0
My%20App/1.35.02 CFNetwork/711.5.6 Darwin/14.0.0
```

I want to match everything starting with `My%20App/` - anything that matches should be allowed access, anything else should get HTTP 403.

I don't want to have to update the nginx config every time a new version of the app comes along.

The following works fine:

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* "My%20App/1.55.01 CFNetwork/711.5.6 Darwin/14.0.0") {
    return 403;
}
```

I figure I need a solution that involves hat (`^`) for "starts with" but I can't get nginx to accept anything I've tried.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with simple `if ($http_user_agent !~ "^My App/") { return 403; }`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the following works.

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* "My%20App/*") {
    return 403;
}
```